# Two-Digit dates in Python

Tags: python, date

I am trying to print the date and month as 2 digit numbers.

```
timestamp = date.today()
difference = timestamp - datetime.timedelta(localkeydays)
localexpiry = '%s%s%s' % (difference.year, difference.month, difference.day)
print localexpiry
```

This gives the output as `201387`. This there anyway to get the output as `20130807`. This is because I am comparing this against a string of a similar format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use date formatting with [`date.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
difference.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> difference = date.today()
>>> difference.strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20130807'
```

You can do the same with the separate integer components of the `date` object, but you need to use the right string formatting parameters; to format an integer to two digits with leading zeros, use `%02d`, for example:

```
localexpiry = '%04d%02d%02d' % (difference.year, difference.month, difference.day)
```

but using `date.strftime()` is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) ([datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__format__), [date](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__format__) have __format__ method):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.date.today()
>>> '{:%Y%m%d}'.format(dt)
'20130807'
>>> format(dt, '%Y%m%d')
'20130807'
```

Comment: It's amazing that there are so many different ways to achieve the same objective in Python. Truly mind-boggling

Answer (score 0):

two digit month, day and four digit year in django like this 04/14/2019: 
{{text1.pub_date|date:"m/d/Y"}}

Comment: The asker was trying to `print` a formatted date. Using Django is a little out of scope for the question.